# Creating a alarm clock application in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Currently i am trying to create a alarm clock application in windows phone 7.
Is there any way i can do it??
Can anyone of you help me with the code.
Thanks

Comment: do you have any reference that i can look at??

Comment: Sadly no clock tutorail but might be able to dig something up. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the set of features introduced in Windows Phone 7.1 SDK (Mango). Following features will enable you to develop this application:

1- Background agents: You will need to run a piece of logic every couple of minutes to check if the alarm is due or not.

[Scheduled Tasks Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

2- Notification: You will need to notify user about by showing a message on the phone and possibly playing a sound:

search for "Toast Notification Sample" in [Code Samples for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

also as [ZombieSheep] suggested: [Reminder Class in Mango](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

3- Background audio play

search for "Background audio play Sample" in [Code Samples for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

4- Ringtones selection: let the user select which ringtone to use!

search for "Ringtones Sample" in [Code Samples for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: ...or plug straight in to the reminders functionality in Mango?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tutorial on WP7 alarms and reminders
[Windows Phone Multitasking–Scheduled Notifications](http://blog.markarteaga.com/WindowsPhoneMultitaskingndashScheduledNotifications.aspx)

Comment: How do i add Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler namespace i couldnt find in when i choose ad reference uner .NET section